# proving that the measure of the points that back infinitely many often is the same as the original set.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, dynamical-systems

Let $X=(\Omega,M,P)$ be a probability space. Let $f:\Omega \to \Omega$ be a function such that for each $A\in M$ $P(A)=P(f^{-1}(A))$ Given an event $B\in M$ we define $B_0=\{x\in X; f^n(x)\in B i.o\}=B\cap \displaystyle \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}f^{-k}(B)$.

I want to prove that $P(B_0)=P(B)$. It's obvious that $P(B_0)\le P(B)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote for each $N\geqslant 1$, $F_N:=B\cap\bigcap_{i\geqslant N}f^{-i}(B^c)$. Since the set $F_N,T^{-N}F_N,\dots, T^{-iN}F_N,\dots$ are disjoint, we have $\mathbb P(F_N)=0$. Therefore, $\mathbb P\left(B\cap\bigcup_{N\geqslant 1}\bigcap_{i\geqslant N}f^{-i}(B^c)\right)=0$.

Comment: I don't understand why $P(F_N)=0$

Comment: We have $\sum_{l=1}^m\mathbb P(f^{-lN}F_N)=\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{l=1}^mf^{-lN}F_N\right)\leqslant 1$, and $f$ preserves the measure, hence $m\mathbb P(F_N)\leqslant 1$ for each $m$.

Comment: Excelent answer :)